# Unable to parse this date

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat

I am getting dates in this format `14-MAY-13 01.17.16.250000 PM` and

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss aaa");
  simpleDateFormat.parse("14-MAY-13 01.17.16.250000 PM")
```

Gives me this exception

`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "14-MAY-13 01.17.16.250000 PM"` ..What should be format of simpledateformat?

Comment: Your format and format of the string do not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `SSSSSS` for milliseconds and replace `:` with `.` to match this part `01.17.16.250000`.

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = 
                 new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS aaa");
```

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS aaa");
```

Answer (score 3):

The format must be corrected (see the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more information). You should also set the Locale to the `SimpleDateFormat` to be sure the month will be parsed with the correct language.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS aaa", Locale.US);
```

If you don't give the Locale, `SimpleDateFormat` will use the default locale of your system which can be not the locale of the given string input.

Comment: Actually, this is a common mistake. The server runs under `Locale.US` and the developer has an other Locale which is probably the same as the input string. The problem is discovered only when running on target environment.

Answer (score 0):

In your Formatstring you expect `hh:mm:ss` but in your input string your have `hh.mm.ss` and you also didn't include the miliseconds.

So the format string should be `dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS aaa`

Answer (score 0):

Simple date format and date formate should be same, try this

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss:SSSSSS aaa");

Date d = simpleDateFormat.parse("14-MAY-13 01:17:16:250000 PM");
```